# Does economics explain why people prefer to live in the same home for long periods of time?

Tags: housing, transaction-costs

Based on actual spatial needs there would seem to be a case for changing homes more often than how often people move in practice; e.g. to respond to where a new job is located in the area, having partners or kids who then move out, etc.

How does economics look at this? I've been thinking of these angles:

- Economic transaction costs (taxes, movers, brokers) - but would one want to move regularly even if all these were low?
- Transaction costs given the specificity of each dwelling situation (hard to assess relative values)?
- Formation of social capital (neighbours, etc.) in the dwelling process that cannot be transferred to a new dwelling situation?
- Formation of "mental" capital - the need to learn new habits inside and outside the new dwelling, e.g. routines, commute, etc.

Comment: I suspect that this remains unanswered because your list of angles already covers all the key points.  The only addition I could suggest, although arguably it's an aspect of the social capital point, is that families may be reluctant to move when it would mean disruption to their children's education.